# Exception to the overflow:hidden; property

Tags: css

How is it possible to make an exception on the `overflow:hidden;` container property to a matched set of child elements?

Here's a sample scene:

```
<div style = "overflow:hidden;">
   <p>item</p>
   <p>item</p>
   <p class="special">item that needs to show itself outside the parent borders</p>
</div>
```

I do have a reason why I'm doing this :] I'm building a pretty complex scrolling menu whose elements are expanding out of the menu's borders. The menu obviously clips everything outside its borders since it's scrolling around.

Here's a chunk of code relevant to the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/Birowsky/fNLbP/15/

Uncomment the marked line in the JavaScript to see the issue below the 'special item'.
You might notice that the scrolling isn't working, it's ok, I think it's fiddle issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to find a way to do this. Even if you do, I'd recommend against using it because it probably won't be future-proof or very cross-browser compatible.

In the case of a menu, you're probably better off putting these items in separate divs. I'd need to see your code in context to recommend a specific way of doing things, but layering your elements kinda like this might work for you:

```
<div style = "overflow: hidden; width: 200px; height: 100px; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: #CCCCCC; z-index: 1;">
   <p>item</p>
   <p>item</p>
</div>
<div style = "overflow: visible; width: 200px; height: 100px; margin: -30px 0 0 0; padding: 0; z-index: 2;">
   <p class="special">item that needs to show itself outside the parent borders</p>
</div>
```

If that doesn't fit your needs, maybe you could describe the structure of your menus better so that we can understand what you need? Do you have a link to an example, perhaps?

**Edit based on new information**

After looking at your [example link](http://jsfiddle.net/Birowsky/fNLbP/15/), it looks like what you want to do is clip content horizontally, while still allowing it to overflow vertically. You can do this by using a very high height value, and then setting a negative bottom margin:

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: 2000px; margin: 0 0 -1960px 0; overflow: hidden;">
    <p>Thisisaverylongsentencedesignedtooverflowthewindowverticallysopleasepermitmetotypeitwithoutandspaces</p>
    Item 1<br />
    Item 2<br />
    Item 3<br />
    Item 4<br />
</div>
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: let me fine tune a bit further and ill get back to you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Birowsky/fNLbP/15/ here it is, uncomment the marked Javascript line to see the issue

Answer (score 7):

You can make the `special` element to be absolutely positioned

```
.special{
 position:absolute;
}
```

But this will only work when the `.special` does not define a position (*top/left/bottom/right*), and also it will not be used if you later want to calculate the height of the parent div..

**example :** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/aT3We/

The requirement though is a bit weird, and it might be better to rethink the whole issue..
(*what exactly are you trying to achieve with this ?*)

Comment: its funny how your code simply works and mine simply doesnt :]

Comment: @Birowsky, i just addressed the problem as it was stated.. If you can elaborate on what you try to do - and how - we might be able to offer more helpful answers :) (*if you can set up a basic example at jsfiddle it would be the best*)

Comment: @Birowsky, here is as close as i can get it to what you want http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/fNLbP/19/ Notice though that now that i made it overflow downwards it also overflows to the left/right so the grey bar will overflow the border to the left as well ..

Comment: Thanx a lot for helping, and good job on fixing the scrolling menu, im still trying to figure how u did that.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem like this where the aforementioned solutions weren't working. There was a list of items in a container, each of which could be varying size depending on how many where in the list (with a minimum). The container was overflow: hidden; and there was a part of the items in the list that was a drop down and would be cut off.

My solution:

```
// get dropdown container position, make a modification, and apply to dropdown
function openDropdown(){
  var offSet = $('.dropdown.open').parent().offset();
  offSet.top = offSet.top + ($('.dropdown.open').parent().height() / 2);
  $('.dropdown.open').offset(offSet);
}

// on scroll reassess dropdown position
$(window).on('scroll', window, function(){
  if($('.dropdown.open')[0] != undefined){
    openDropdown();
  }
});

// on click close open dropdowns and open this one
$('body').on('click', '.dropdown', function(){
  $('.dropdown.open').removeClass('open');
  $(this).addClass('open');
  openDropdown();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to do this? Maybe a better solution can be made.

I don't think that defining `overflow: auto;` selectively is possible, as `overflow` is applied to the parent, not it's children, so it's like having `color: red` and `color: blue` on the same element, at the same time; they just don't make sense when put together (bad example, but you get the idea).

Comment: I do have a reason why i'm doing this :]
 I'm building a pretty complex scrolling menu who's elements are expanding out of the menu's borders. The menu obviously clips everything outside it's borders since it's scrolling around.

Comment: Okay, that makes things a bit clearer. So you're looking to make an animated dropdown menu? If you were to edit that info into your original question, people could suggest better or simpler methods of achieving your desired outcome (as IE is *really* funky when it comes to `position` attributes, so don't be surprised when your site has a seizure with IE).